# A question in calculus of variations

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Consider the functional

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}\,dt$$

where (x(t),y(t)) is a $C^2$ curve in the plane. Firstly, How can I derive Euler-Lagrange equations?

Secondly, How to prove that the smooth path of least length between the two points $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$ in the plane is a
straight line. That is, prove that $x = t; y = 0$ has the least length among all $C_2$ curves $(x(t), y(t))$ with $(x(0), y(0))= (0; 0),(x(1); y(1))= (1; 0)$, and $dx=dt$ and $dy=dt$ never simultaneously zero.

Comment: For the first part, I think the Euler Lagrange equations can be derived using:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}-\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'})=0$

and

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'})=0$,

where $L$ is the function inside the integral? is this right?

Comment: For given $x(t), y(t)$, that integral is a number, not a function

Comment: I thought he had mistyped something, I didn't think his function was $(x,y)\mapsto \int_{[0,1]} \sqrt{x_t^2+y_t^2}dt$.

Comment: It is not a function; it's a functional.

Answer (score 2):

**APPROACH $1$:  HEURISTIC APPROACH**

We can approach the problem **heuristically** (i.e., this is ***not*  a rigorous development**) as follows.

Let $J[x,y]=\int_0^1 \sqrt{x'^2(y)+y'^2(t)}\,dt$ and let $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ be "**small**" variations in $x$ and $y$, respectively, such that $\delta x(0)=\delta x(1)=\delta y(0)=\delta y(1)=0$.

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\delta J[x,y]&=\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{(x'+\delta x')^2+(y'+\delta y')^2}-\sqrt{x'^2(y)+y'^2(t)}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x'(t)\delta x'(t)+y'(t)\delta y'(t)}{\sqrt{x'^2(y)+y'^2(t)}}\,dt+\underbrace{O(\delta^2x',\delta^2 y')}_{\text{Higher Order "Small" Terms}}\\\\
&\overbrace{=}_{IBP}\underbrace{\left.\left(\frac{x'(t)\delta x(t)}{\sqrt{x'^2(y)+y'^2(t)}}+\frac{y'(t)\delta y(t)}{\sqrt{x'^2(y)+y'^2(t)}}\right)\right|_{t=0}^{t=1}}_{=0\,\text{Since the variations vanish at the end points}}\\\\
&-\int_0^1 \left(\delta x(t)\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{x'(t)}{\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}}\right)+\delta y(t)\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{y'(t)}{\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}}\right)\right)\\\\
&+\underbrace{O(\delta^2x',\delta^2 y')}_{\text{Considered Negligibly Small}}\\\\
\end{align}$$

If $\delta J[x,y]=0$ for all $\delta x$ and $\delta y$, then the first variation is $0$ when

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{x'(t)}{\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}}\right)=0 \tag 1$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{x'(t)}{\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}}\right)=0\tag 2$$

Integrating $(1)$ and $(2)$, solving the resulting expressions, and enforcing the initial and final conditions reveals

$$x(t)=t$$

and

$$y(t)=0$$

---

**APPROACH $2$:  RIGOROUS APPROACH**

Note that the integrand of the functional $J[x,y]$ depends explicitly on only $x'$ and $y'$, not $x$ and $y$.  The Euler-Lagrange Equations are given by $(1)$ and $(2)$ since

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}\,dt =\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}\,dt=0$$

and

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x'}\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}\,dt =\frac{x'(t)}{\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y'}\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}\,dt =\frac{y'(t)}{\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}}$$

Therefore, starting with $(1)$ and $(2)$ and proceeding as outlined in Approach $1$.

Comment: hmmm. A heuristic approach? Interesting. I'll read through it when I have time. Accept my +1 as payment in the meantime :)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you Brevan.  Much appreciative!  -Mark

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Comment: Well, since your comment showed up in my inbox, I suppose I'll respond XD I did read through your heuristic approach as I said I would, and I think it is very well written, if a bit confusing at times due to brevity. While I think heuristics are a great idea, you might want to be a little more explicit about what is happening for clarity's sake (in particular, you might mention why we ignore the higher order terms). Of course, if the OP is familiar with the material this might not be necessary :)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I wonder why this showed up in your inbox.  I didn't address it to you.  In any case, I did provide a rigorous approach which should suffice.  But to answer the question, we are looking for conditions for which the First Variation vanishes.  The "higher-order terms" are considered negligible since the variations $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ are considered "small." I've edited to make this more explicit (hopefully).

Comment: I have no idea why I was tagged; nevertheless, I like the edit! Hopefully the OP responds soon

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you my friend for the suggestion!  Much appreciated.